# Pointing Domain Name to Microsoft Azure web app and configure the app for the new domain

Tags: domains, azure

I have bought a domain name on GoDaddy, hotelmontecristobg.com. I think I have configured it properly because when I browse to hotelmontecristobg.com

> Error 404 - Web app not found appears which says
>
> The web app you have attempted to reach is not available in this Microsoft Azure >App Service region. This could be due to one of several reasons:
>
> 1. The web app owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure App Service, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it. Click here to read more.
> 2. The web app owner has moved the web app to a different region, but the DNS cache is still directing to the old IP Address that was used in the previous region. Click here to read more.

But then when I browse my `Web > Setting > Custom Domains and SSL > Bring External Domains > under domain names I have hotelmontecristobg.azurewebsites.net, so under it I added hotelmontecristobg.com, but when i try to save it an error appear :

> The DNS records for 'Hotelmontecristobg.com' that points to 'hotelmontecristobg.azurewebsites.net' could not be located

If you want to configure bla bla bla. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How have you set up your domain name in the DNS?? In your case, I am sure you want to use a CNAME record pointing your domain name to your app space.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a CNAME record for both the base domain and www.domain.com within GoDaddy.

```
TYPE: CNAME
NAME: awverify
VALUE: awverify.hotelmontecristobg.azurewebsites.net

TYPE: CNAME
NAME: awverify.www
VALUE: awverify.hotelmontecristobg.azurewebsites.net
```

Once the record is created in GoDaddy, you can then bring the external domain into Azure.